# NLog and maxArchiveDays

Tags: nlog

I have NLog setup and I'm using maxArchiveDays="30" and archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence".  My questions is will that work, per https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target maxArchiveDays is not supported with archiveNumbering="Sequence", since they didn't say "DateAndSequence" will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES the documentation is correct. `MaxArchiveDays` will work for `archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"` and `archiveNumbering="Date"`.

AND it will also work for `archiveNumbering="Sequence"` when not having specified a custom `archiveFileName="..."` path (NLog v5.0 will remove this restriction).